# jQuery in Safari is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, browser, safari

I have the following code to open and close my side nav with a overlay.. it works perfectly on chrome but in safari it just breaks so I am guessing their is some compatibility issue with the version of code. There are no errors displayed in Safari

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $('.sidenav-button').click(function() {
            if ($(this).hasClass('show')) {
                $(".sidenavbody-overlay").fadeIn(500);
                $(".sidenav-button, .sidenav-panel").animate({
                    left: "-=25%"
                }, 700, function() {
                    // Animation complete.
                });
                $(this).html('').removeClass('show').addClass('hide');

            } else {
                $(".sidenavbody-overlay").fadeOut(400);
                $(".sidenav-button, .sidenav-panel").animate({
                    left: "+=25%"
                }, 700, function() {
                    // Animation complete.
                });
                $(this).html('').removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
            }
        });
    });

    $('.sidenavbody-overlay').click(function() {

        $('.sidenav-button').trigger('click');
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors in Safari?

Comment: Yes and nothing shows up.... It is ignoring most of my JS code

Comment: Have you found solution? In my case it seems like Safari is calling ready function too early. I have no proof and my problem is a bit different but still seems to have connection with whats happening to you.